# Polymorphism design, template as abstract class

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, factory

How do you design polymorphism when you have a member which type depends on some constraints.

Say I have this :

```
template<typename T>
class Base
{
public:
  Base() = default;
  virtual ~Base() = default;
  T member;
};

class DerivedA : public Base<int>
{
public:
  DerivedA() {member = 5;}
};

class DerivedB : public Base<float>
{
public:
  DerivedB() = default;
};
```

I want to be able to create a new derived object depending on different parameters, i.e :

```
Base *b;
if (something)
    b = new DerivedA();
else
    b = new DerivedB();
```

Obviously I can't do this since I need to provide template parameters for the declaration of `b`.

**Is this bad design ? How do you handle this ?**

I could write a small wrapper :

```
class Wrapper() {};

template<typename T>
class Base : public Wrapper
{
// ...
};

Wrapper a, b;
a = new DerivedA;
b = new DerivedB;
```

But then I won't have access directly to `member` or other methods declared in `Base` or `Derived`. I would need to cast : `reinterpret_cast<DerivedA*>(a)->member`, making polymorphism useless.

Thanks

Comment: There is a problem in your design... The Wrapper interface should be ok, but you will have to reverse the problem for it to work.

Comment: this comes to my mind http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design

Comment: Suppose `Base *b;` works somehow (by miracle, by hacking the compiler, whatever). What would you *do* with `b`? Can you provide a usage example?

Answer (score 0):

Wrapper design should be exactly what you are looking for. The problem is that c++ is statically typed, so you can't declare member without specifying its type. The common way to avoid this is to design a base class which supports all the functionality you want, and implement a specific behaviour in derived classes, just as you did.

Probably the problem is that your class doesn't support all the functionality you need. Try to avoid using member directly and wrap its usage into virtual methods. Reimplement these methods in your derived classes.

If this is still not an option, consider methods for extracting your member. Maybe virtual getters and setters with appropriate conversions.

As a last resort, consider boost::variant, boost::any. But really they are implemented using the technique similar to your wrapper. So you get wrapper for the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the "access" depends on the template parameter `T` (such reading `Base.member`), then you have to supply it *somehow*. Casting to one of the derived classes is one way to do it, but you don't need the `reinterpret_cast`. You need to start using pointers/references, to avoid the cut-off and let the *substitutability* work correctly:

```
Wrapper *a, *b;
a = new DerivedA;
b = new DerivedB;

int a_member = static_cast<DerivedA*>(a)->member;
float b_member = static_cast<DerivedB*>(b)->member;
```

And if you add a virtual method to `Wrapper` to make it polymorphic, you can do dynamic cast as well:

```
DerivedB* b_derived = dynamic_cast<DerivedB*>(b);
if (b_derived != nullptr) {
    float b_member = b_derived->member;
    // ...
}
```